# Not able to generate a random array of categorical labels

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, random, random-seed

I have a random state with a fixed seed I am using to make my predictive results replicable:

```
rng = np.random.RandomState(101)
len(finalTestSentences) = 500
```

I am trying to use this seed to generate an array of random categorical variables using a unique list of possibilities. Here's an example (I used `set` on my training labels to generate the unique labels I have):

```
unique_train_labels = set([u'bla', u'blee', u'blu', u'ma'])
```

I then do:

```
categorical_random = np.array[rng.choice(unique_train_labels, len(finalTestSentences))]
```

But I am getting:

```
categorical_random = np.array[rng.choice(unique_train_labels, len(finalTestSentences))]
  File "mtrand.pyx", line 1072, in mtrand.RandomState.choice (numpy/random/mtrand/mtrand.c:11545)
ValueError: a must be 1-dimensional or an integer
```

Note, this was from this workaround [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/5344)

What is going wrong and how can I achieve my aim?

Comment: It is not accepting a set. You can convert it to a list once you get the unique ones `rng.choice(list(unique_train_labels), len(finalTestSentences))`

Comment: @ayhan that has solved it - I didn't know you don't need a unique set as an input, you can even take a non-unique list for `random.choice`

Comment: I am not sure about the implementation though. That might introduce bias against the nonunique ones (if they appear more frequently). Let me try.

Comment: If you try it with `rng.choice(['a', 'a', 'b'], 10**6)` you'll see that 66% of the time it will generate a.

Comment: @ayhan would you mind placing an answer here for the benefit of SO users?

Comment: Sure, I posted an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the definition of [`np.random.choice`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/c62b20d10c05c07511553972d1c21e5845aa7d6f/numpy/random/mtrand/mtrand.pyx#L1293), you'll see that `a`, the population, is converted to a numpy array by

```
a = np.array(a, copy=False)
```

If a is a set, the conversion is a little different. For example, `np.array([1, 2, 3])` gives an array with three elements: `array([1, 2, 3])` but `np.array({1, 2, 3})` gives an array with a single element where the element is a set. Because of the dimension problem, numpy raises the ValueError.

To avoid that you can either convert your set to a list with:

```
rng.choice(list(unique_train_labels), len(finalTestSentences))
```

Or directly use np.unique to get the unique labels:

```
rng.choice(np.unique([u'bla', u'blee', u'blu', u'ma']), len(finalTestSentences))
```